# How to get the background color of the current view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, gradient, background-color

I'd like to set the gradient second color to the color of the background.

I tried to set `.clear`, but for some reason it becomes dark. If I use `.white` the radient is as expected in light mode.
The best for me is to use the background color to handle themes.

So how do I get the background color?

````
// Fill gradient
                        line
                            .trim(to: animate ? 1 : 0)
                            .fill(
                                LinearGradient(
                                    gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                                        Color(graphColor),
                                        <content backgroundColor>
                                        //.white
                                        //.clear
                                    ]),
                                    startPoint: .top,
                                    endPoint: .bottom
                                )

                            )
                        ```
````

Comment: what the "background color" refers to? if it is your own defined color, I'm sure you have the value of it, or are you referring to dark/light mode? Could you give more detail?. Also, I am using Xcode 14 with iOS 16, .clear basically gives you whatever color/ui behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use system background, like

```
LinearGradient(
    gradient: Gradient(colors: [
        Color(graphColor),
        Color(uiColor: UIColor.systemBackground)    // << here !!
    ]),
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
```